# На что ругается django?

Tags: html, css, python, django

Подскажите, на что ругается django?

Ошибка:

```
ValueError at /account/register/
The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/gamzat/Django/tutorial',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Mon, 10 Jul 2017 02:32:27 +0000
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    name = 'Rasulov Gamzat'

    args = {'myName': name, 'numbers': numbers}
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)

def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

## reg_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда форма невалидна, то возвращает None, вместо ответа, на что и ругается джанга.

Comment: В чем она не валидно то

Comment: @Расулов Гамзат, сам метод формы решил, что присланные данные неверные. Может поля были пустые, может ещё что-то.

Comment: @Расулов Гамзат, там просто надо дописать какой ответ вернуть, в том случае, если форма невалидна, у вас этот вариант не предусмотрен.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, тут все просто. Ваш view ничего не вернул. Скорее всего, дело в том, что не проходит условие: if form.is_valid(). Т.е. вам необходимо вернуть Response с ошибками.

Comment: Смысле не подходить я смотрел туториал, там он также все сделал, у него все сработала, версия джанго тоже самое было, я где-то ошибку допустил, но не в if

Comment: Тут без вариантов. Либо приходит пустая форма, либо она невалидная.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуете вот так:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/account')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(u'Куда прёшь?', status_code=400)
```

Comment: Пробовал не работает

Comment: Если Вы приняли ответ выше, то это не может не работать. Если, конечно не  забыть сделать импорт HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

Просто напишите так:

```
def register(request):
form_class = RegistrationForm
form = form.class(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
if form.is_valid():
form.save()
return redirect('/account')
else:
form = RegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', {'form': form})
```